# How does Australia fit into 'New World' / 'Old World' dichotomy?

Tags: terminology, biogeography

How are places such as Australia and New Zealand classified when differentiating geographic areas based on 'New World' and 'Old World?'

My understanding is:

- New World = North America + South America (+ Central America)
- Old World = Europe + Asia + Africa

This is biologically relevant via biogeography:

- Ex: *neo*tropical vs. *paleo*tropical (comparable to *New* and *Old* World Tropics)

I've seen online sources group Australia / New Zealand in both New *and* Old World (or in neither). So what's the right answer?

Reputably cited answers only please!

Comment: Please comment as to why you down voted

Comment: I do not see any reason to downvote this question either. +1

Comment: I downvoted the question because it's not biologically relevant. The concept of Old and new worlds reflects only the history of European exploration and colonization. As for biology, there may be more differences between north and South America than between North America and Asia.

Comment: @IMil - makes sense and thanks for sharing. It's basically my answer :-)

Comment: @IMIL but it *IS* relevant for biology. I gave a direct example demonstrating so (and see Christiaan's new world primate example below). Just because it's not about cells, cancer, or microbes doesn't mean it's not part of biology. Biogeogrpahy is a prominent and legitimate sub-field of biology. Further, the relative difference between N & S are irrelevant to the validity or relevance of this question. New World and Old world may have originated in a more historically dated context, but that also does not disqualify a question pertaining to their use. (Besides, they are still often employed).

Comment: ...Your comment is equivalent to downvoting a question that asks for clarification, for example, about the historical taxanomic kingdom of ["Monera"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monera). Yes it has older origins (and actually is now defunct), but that doesn't mean that studying or understanding the concept of the Monera kingdom (*typically through questioning*) is irrelevant. I fully disagree with your approach to judging biological relevance.

Answer (score 4):

First off - this is an answer without citations. I looked for them, but couldn't find any. The terminology is undoubtedly described in reputable sources, but it is unlikely a paper is dedicated solely to explain this terminology, making literature searches tricky. Having said that -

I discussed this question with an anthropologist and she agrees with my idea that the terminology Old and New World is a historic and Euro-centric one, dating back to the [colonial times](http://www.americaslibrary.gov/jb/colonial/jb_colonial_subj.html) when Europe viewed itself as the center of the world.

The [Americas were discovered](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/columbus.htm) relatively early, around 1492. It was designated the [New World](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/columbus.htm). Australia wasn't found until [around 1606](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/columbus.htm). By that time the New World was already a century old and very likely already solidly associated with the Americas.

The New World, in a biological context, is often used to describe groups of closely related species found in the Americas and not elsewhere, such as [New World monkeys](http://anthro.palomar.edu/primate/prim_5.htm). In certain areas of expertise the terminology is baked in in the jargon, .e.g,  monkey and ape behavioral research areas. New World monkeys can be referred to by the *Cebidae*, as per the [Linnaeus's classification](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/history/linnaeus.html). However, due to practical reasons geographical clustering of species can be more convenient.

The term New World means different things in a biological context or in the context of [wines](http://vinepair.com/wine-101/guide-old-world-vs-new-world-wines/), for example (Americas versus Americas + Australia - admittedly Australian wines are pretty good).

In all, I think the terminology 'New and Old World' is confusing, rooted in historical considerations. Australia as well as Antarctica don't fit in this terminology.